# Android on demand asset pack download error

Tags: android

I am working with on demand asset pack.
Its working on some devices. On some devices its failed with below error. I am not seeing the reason of the error in anywhere. Could you please help me to debug this error.

```
Download not permitted under the current device circumstances (e.g. in background).
Constant Value: -7 (0xfffffff9)
```